# pip install cryptography -> error...failed with exit status 1120

Tags: python, windows, pip, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to install the [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) module for python yet I keep getting errors and so far I have been able to solve each one as they come including:

1. [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)
2. [mysql-python install problem using virtualenv, windows, pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972259/mysql-python-install-problem-using-virtualenv-windows-pip)
3. [Installing lxml for Python 3.4 on Windows x 86 (32 bit) with Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944465/installing-lxml-for-python-3-4-on-windows-x-86-32-bit-with-visual-studio-c-2)
4. [Failing to run pip install cryptography on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22543726/failing-to-run-pip-install-cryptography-on-windows-7)

However I have ran into an error that no matter how hard I look I find nothing so I decided I shall do what everyone else has done in the past and ask.

What do I need to do to get the `error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Visual Studio\\14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120` error to go away so I can install the cryptographic module.

P.S. Yes I have tried `easy_install`

---

### System Info

- Windows 7 Home Premium - Service Pack 1 - 64-bit - AMD64x
- Python 3.5.0a4

---

### Setting up the environment

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Visual Studio\14.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"
set INCLUDE=C:\ProgramData\Runtime\OpenSSL\include;%INCLUDE%
set LIB=C:\ProgramData\Runtime\OpenSSL\lib;C:\ProgramData\Runtime\OpenSSL\lib\VC\static;%LIB%
```

---

### Checking the path

```
C:\PROGRA~1\Calibre2
C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1\120\Tools\Binn\
C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\Dnvm\
C:\PROGRA~2\GNU\GnuPG\pub
C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\8.1\WINDOW~1\
C:\PROGRA~3\Oracle\Java\javapath
C:\PROGRA~3\Runtime\JAVASC~1\nodejs
C:\PROGRA~3\Runtime\Perl\STRAWB~1\c\bin
C:\PROGRA~3\Runtime\Perl\STRAWB~1\perl\bin
C:\PROGRA~3\Runtime\Python\
C:\PROGRA~3\Runtime\Python\Scripts\
C:\PROGRA~3\Runtime\libxml2\bin
C:\PROGRA~3\Runtime\libxslt\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Visual Studio\14.0\Common7\IDE\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Visual Studio\14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Visual Studio\14.0\Common7\Tools
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Visual Studio\14.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Visual Studio\14.0\VC\BIN
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Visual Studio\14.0\VC\VCPackages
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86
C:\ProgramData\Runtime\Gradle\bin
C:\ProgramData\Runtime\Lua\bin
C:\ProgramData\Runtime\OpenSSL/bin
C:\Users\Brandon\.dnx\bin
C:\Users\Brandon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\Windows\system32
S:\xampp\php
```

---

### pip install cryptography

```
Collecting cryptography
  Using cached cryptography-0.8.2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyasn1 in c:\programdata\runtime\python\lib\site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.4.1 in c:\programdata\runtime\python\lib\site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in c:\programdata\runtime\python\lib\site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cffi>=0.8 in c:\programdata\runtime\python\lib\site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pycparser in c:\programdata\runtime\python\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=0.8->cryptography)
Installing collected packages: cryptography
  Running setup.py install for cryptography
    Complete output from command C:\ProgramData\Runtime\Python\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='S:\\Temp\\Local\\pip-build-j3dfyfa3\\cryptography\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record S:\Temp\Local\pip-igpv1y8a-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography
    copying src\cryptography\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography
    copying src\cryptography\fernet.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography
    copying src\cryptography\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography
    copying src\cryptography\x509.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography
    copying src\cryptography\__about__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography
    copying src\cryptography\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\backends
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\interfaces.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\backends
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\multibackend.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\backends
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\backends
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\cmac.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\constant_time.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\hashes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\hmac.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\padding.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\backends\commoncrypto
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\commoncrypto\backend.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\backends\commoncrypto
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\commoncrypto\ciphers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\backends\commoncrypto
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\commoncrypto\hashes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\backends\commoncrypto
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\commoncrypto\hmac.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\backends\commoncrypto
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\commoncrypto\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\backends\commoncrypto
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\backend.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\ciphers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\cmac.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\dsa.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\ec.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\hashes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\hmac.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\rsa.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\x509.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\commoncrypto
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\commoncrypto\binding.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\commoncrypto
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\commoncrypto\cf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\commoncrypto
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\commoncrypto\common_cryptor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\commoncrypto
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\commoncrypto\common_digest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\commoncrypto
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\commoncrypto\common_hmac.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\commoncrypto
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\commoncrypto\common_key_derivation.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\commoncrypto
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\commoncrypto\secimport.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\commoncrypto
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\commoncrypto\secitem.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\commoncrypto
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\commoncrypto\seckey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\commoncrypto
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\commoncrypto\seckeychain.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\commoncrypto
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\commoncrypto\sectransform.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\commoncrypto
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\commoncrypto\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\commoncrypto
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\aes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\bignum.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\binding.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\bio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\cmac.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\cms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\conf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\crypto.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\dh.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\dsa.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\ec.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\ecdh.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\ecdsa.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\engine.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\err.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\evp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\hmac.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\nid.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\objects.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\opensslv.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\osrandom_engine.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\pem.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\pkcs12.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\pkcs7.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\rand.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\rsa.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\ssl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\x509.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\x509name.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\x509v3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\x509_vfy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\dh.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\dsa.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\ec.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\padding.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\rsa.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers\algorithms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers\base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers\modes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\interfaces
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\interfaces\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\interfaces
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf\hkdf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf\pbkdf2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor\hotp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor\totp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor
    running egg_info
    writing entry points to src\cryptography.egg-info\entry_points.txt
    writing top-level names to src\cryptography.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing requirements to src\cryptography.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing dependency_links to src\cryptography.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing src\cryptography.egg-info\PKG-INFO

    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'src\cryptography.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
    writing manifest file 'src\cryptography.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\__pycache__
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\__pycache__\_Cryptography_cffi_15f8accfx62b488b1.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\__pycache__
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\__pycache__\_Cryptography_cffi_89292e72x399b1113.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\__pycache__
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\__pycache__\_Cryptography_cffi_c4c16865xffc7b1ce.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\__pycache__
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\src
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\src\constant_time.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\src
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\src\constant_time.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\src
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\src\padding.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\src
    copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\src\padding.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\src
    running build_ext

    building '_Cryptography_cffi_89292e72x399b1113' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src\cryptography
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src\cryptography\hazmat
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\__pycache__

    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Visual Studio\14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\ProgramData\Runtime\Python\include -IC:\ProgramData\Runtime\Python\include /Tcsrc\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\__pycache__\_Cryptography_cffi_89292e72x399b1113.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\__pycache__\_Cryptography_cffi_89292e72x399b1113.obj
    _Cryptography_cffi_89292e72x399b1113.c
    src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\__pycache__\_Cryptography_cffi_89292e72x399b1113.c(2539): warning C4048: different array subscripts: 'unsigned char (*)[0]' and 'unsigned char (*)[32]'
    src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\__pycache__\_Cryptography_cffi_89292e72x399b1113.c(2540): warning C4048: different array subscripts: 'unsigned char (*)[0]' and 'unsigned char (*)[32]'
    src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\__pycache__\_Cryptography_cffi_89292e72x399b1113.c(2567): warning C4048: different array subscripts: 'unsigned char (*)[0]' and 'unsigned char (*)[48]'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Visual Studio\14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\ProgramData\Runtime\Python\libs /LIBPATH:C:\ProgramData\Runtime\Python\PCbuild\amd64 libeay32mt.lib ssleay32mt.lib advapi32.lib crypt32.lib gdi32.lib user32.lib ws2_32.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__Cryptography_cffi_89292e72x399b1113 build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\__pycache__\_Cryptography_cffi_89292e72x399b1113.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\_Cryptography_cffi_89292e72x399b1113.cp35-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\__pycache__\_Cryptography_cffi_89292e72x399b1113.cp35-win_amd64.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\__pycache__\_Cryptography_cffi_89292e72x399b1113.cp35-win_amd64.pyd.manifest_Cryptography_cffi_89292e72x399b1113.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit__Cryptography_cffi_89292e72x399b1113' specified multiple times; using first specification
        Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\__pycache__\_Cryptography_cffi_89292e72x399b1113.cp35-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\__pycache__\_Cryptography_cffi_89292e72x399b1113.cp35-win_amd64.exp
        libeay32mt.lib(cryptlib.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sscanf referenced in function OPENSSL_cpuid_setup
        libeay32mt.lib(v3_utl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol sscanf
        libeay32mt.lib(cryptlib.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _vsnwprintf referenced in function OPENSSL_showfatal
        libeay32mt.lib(cryptlib.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _vsnprintf referenced in function OPENSSL_showfatal
        ssleay32mt.lib(t1_enc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
        libeay32mt.lib(txt_db.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
        libeay32mt.lib(gost_eng.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
        libeay32mt.lib(ui_openssl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
        ssleay32mt.lib(s3_srvr.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
        ssleay32mt.lib(d1_both.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
        libeay32mt.lib(cryptlib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
        libeay32mt.lib(eng_openssl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
        libeay32mt.lib(pem_lib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
        libeay32mt.lib(e_capi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
        ssleay32mt.lib(s3_srvr.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol fprintf referenced in function ssl3_accept
        ssleay32mt.lib(d1_both.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol fprintf
        ssleay32mt.lib(t1_enc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol fprintf
        libeay32mt.lib(txt_db.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol fprintf
        libeay32mt.lib(eng_openssl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol fprintf
        libeay32mt.lib(pem_lib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol fprintf
        libeay32mt.lib(gost_eng.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol fprintf
        libeay32mt.lib(ui_openssl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol fprintf
        libeay32mt.lib(gost_eng.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol printf referenced in function bind_gost
        libeay32mt.lib(pqueue.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol printf
        libeay32mt.lib(e_cswift.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sprintf referenced in function cswift_mod_exp
        libeay32mt.lib(dso_win32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol sprintf
        build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cryptography\_Cryptography_cffi_89292e72x399b1113.cp35-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 7 unresolved externals

    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Visual Studio\\14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "C:\ProgramData\Runtime\Python\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='S:\\Temp\\Local\\pip-build-j3dfyfa3\\cryptography\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record S:\Temp\Local\pip-igpv1y8a-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in S:\Temp\Local\pip-build-j3dfyfa3\cryptography
```

Comment: This is probably way out-of-date information, but just in case… I notice that your Visual Studio is in `Program Files (x86)`, not `Program Files`. Microsoft at least _used_ to distribute free 32-bit-only versions of Visual Studio, which couldn't be used for building 64-bit apps because they were missing the 64-bit SDK. Do they still do that? Because not having the MSVCRT from the 64-bit SDK would explain why the linker can't find things like `sscanf`…

Comment: You are likely missing a library and/or it's development sources so the linker is failing to link the C-extensions in cryptography.

Comment: There are pre-built [cryptography wheels](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cryptography/0.2.2) -- Install one of those so you don't have to build it.

Comment: @abarnert, it's a 64-bit compiler:  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Visual Studio\14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe`. Visual Studio installs all compilers under `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`. The OP's OpenSSL libs clearly are not built using Visual Studio 2015 (14.0). The new VC++ is a major update and reorganization of the Windows C runtime, so OpenSSL will have to be built from source.

Comment: Wheels installed correctly, I have the 64-bit compiler like @eryksun said.  Could it be that I am using a prerelease version of python?  What other things should I try?

Comment: pip installs wheels out of the box. The `wheel` package is for building wheels, so you can build a package once and deploy to multiple development environments, but you still need to be able to build the package. If you can't build OpenSSL from source, you'll need to use Python 3.4 and either the pre-built 3.4 wheel that can be pip installed from PyPI, or build your own version using Visual Studio 2010 or the Windows SDK 7.1.

Comment: downgrading to python 3.4.3 made it work